# How to get table into a Dataframe with BeautifullSoup

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

It seams that Beautifull Soup is not able to retrieve the info from a table.

What I am trying to do is to retrieve the table with header and save it to a dataframe in pands. Any help is really much appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Create an URL object
url = 'xxxx'
# Create object page
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
data = soup.find_all("table", id="cve_table", attrs={"class": "table"})
print(len(data))
headers = []
for body in data:
    print(body)
    for item in body:
        title = item.text
        print(title)
        headers.append(title)

print(headers)
```

All I got is this:

```
<table class="table cell-border table-striped table-condensed table-hover" id="cve_table">
        <tbody></tbody>

    </table>
  
['\n        ', '', '\n\n    ']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that the table is rendered by javascript, so when `requests` loads the HTML page, the table is empty. When investigating the page sources, it could be seen, that the table is rendered with the function called in the last script element. This function takes as a parameter the data structure needed to render the table. It can be extracted as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
import json
from collections import defaultdict

# Create an URL object
url = 'https://cve.rayvyn.net/rayvyn'

# Create object page
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")

dct = defaultdict(list)

script = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "script" and "get_all_cve_data" in tag.text) 
if script:
  result = re.search('\((.*)\)', script.text)
  text = result.group(1)
  data = json.loads(json.loads(text))
  for row in data:
    dct['CVE ID'].append(row[0])
    dct['Feed'].append(row[1])
    dct['Date Modified'].append(row[2])
    dct['Description'].append(row[3])
    dct['Vector'].append(row[4])
    dct['Vendor'].append(row[5])
    dct['Product'].append(row[6])
    dct['Advisory Link'].append(row[7])
else:
  print('Script tag with function get_all_cve_data() not found')

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
df
```

An alternative approach would be using selenium framework:

```
import re
import json

from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from collections import defaultdict

# Create an URL object
url = 'https://cve.rayvyn.net/rayvyn'


# delay for selenium web driver wait
DELAY = 30

# create selenium driver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('<<path to chromedriver.exe>>', options = chrome_options)

# open web page
driver.get(url)

script = WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//script[contains(text(), 'get_all_cve_data')]")))

dct = defaultdict(list)

if script:
  result = re.search('\((.*)\)', script.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
  text = result.group(1)
  data = json.loads(text)
  print(data)
else:
  print('Script tag with function get_all_cve_data() not found')
  
driver.quit()

data = json.loads(json.loads(text))
for row in data:
  dct['CVE ID'].append(row[0])
  dct['Feed'].append(row[1])
  dct['Date Modified'].append(row[2])
  dct['Description'].append(row[3])
  dct['Vector'].append(row[4])
  dct['Vendor'].append(row[5])
  dct['Product'].append(row[6])
  dct['Advisory Link'].append(row[7])

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
df
```

Please note, that for using selenium there also will be selenium webdriver needed (as a separate executable). It will simulate browser behavior and (among other features) will wait for the javascript code on the page to be executed and HTML code to be rendered.

Comment: Thank you Alexandra! I got an error while running your code: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' | at this line `text = result.group(1)`

Comment: Try to output the content of the last `script` tag before parsing it with the regular expression: `print(script.text)`. It should contain call of the javascript function `get_all_cve_data` to which as a parameter is passed the JSON string with the data from the table. Does it have another content for you?

Comment: Updated answer to make search for the `script` tag more precise, added message when element was not found

Comment: Thank you Alexandra! Now i got `Script tag with function get_all_cve_data() not found`. There is the same text as from your backend.

Comment: This means, that the script tag is rendered with another javascript as well. I added selenium solution, you could try it as well.

Comment: is there a way to extract the data as json file? currently i see there are lists of lists. @Alexandra Dudkina

Comment: It seems that `json.loads(text)` wasn't enough to parse the string content, try to wrap it into `data = json.loads(json.loads(text))`. I updated answer with parsing of the data into pandas dataframe, but it can be parsed into any other data structure.